# Deploying Dll to sharepoint sharepoint site throwing exception

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, custom-timer-job, gac

I was created a Two Project in one solution One for feature activation and anthor one is for TimerJob.
Manually i deployed the solution or If i take a wsp and put it in patch this two solution was deploying without any problem.

I have a another solution that is BusinessLogic dll. Dll are in GAC Folder.
if i deployed this solution from visual studio it was deploying.But when i take a wsp and put it in patch It was throwing following exception.My doubt is Because of this event receiver and timer job only this Error came or something else.Please someone give me solution for this

Only this problem happens when i installed my First two projects Feature activation and Timer job project.

Anyone know why this happening how can i solve this issue.Please someone help for this.
Thanks in Advance.

In this local patch wsp folder i will put Businesslogiccdll.wsp and run the setup the following error came -Exception has been thrown by Target of an Invocation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is really not self-explanatory, however the only problem is that you **don’t have enough permissions** on the `Site` or `Web`. Even if you are a **farm admin** and **local admin** on the server, some SharePoint PowerShell Commands will not allow you to run at the `Site` or `Web` level.

Easiest way to fix it, since you already have access to the server, give yourself **Full Control at the Web Application Level (in User Policy)** and you shouldn’t have this problem anymore!